# Regular expression failed replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use Regular expression to replace this text :

```
[Button size="Big" color="#000"] test [/Button]
```

to `Button`, I used this site http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html but not working the replace.
the Regular expression `\[Button([^\]]*)\[/Button]`,it give me the result `String is same as before replace!` what the mistake?

Comment: because the regex is wrong.

Comment: You don't need the grouping in this case

Comment: i need it in another case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `([^\]]*)` part of your regex will stop matching before the closing `]` of first tag. So, you don't have the pattern to match string - `"] test "` thereafter.

Modify your regex to:

```
\[Button([^\]]*][^\[]*)\[/Button]
```

Comment: your code is working, but i need ` size="Big" color="#000"] test ` group like my code

Comment: it doesn't work when the text is `[Button size="Big" color="#000"][Small] test [/Small][/Button]` how can i fix it?

Comment: @magedali Don't use regex in case of nested tags. You should parse the text.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this, it matches properly and also matches the insides.

```
\[Button([^\]]*)\](.*?)\[/Button\]
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex of

> `\[Button.*\]`

and the replacement string of `Button` should be enough.